# Finding a primary decomposition of an ideal.

Tags: commutative-algebra, primary-decomposition

I'm studying commutative algebra and I need to find, for the course I'm attending, the primary decompositions of the following ideals, with some extra questions:

> In $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, find, if you can, two primary decompositions of the ideal $(x^2y, xy^2)$, and find all isolated primes. Is the ideal radical? Is the decomposition unique? In the same ring, find a primary decomposition of $H = (y - x^2, x - y)$, and find whether it's radical or not.

> In $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$, find two different primary decompositions of $I = (xyz^2,xy^2)$, and the associated isolated primes. In the same ring, find a primary decomposition of $J = (x,z,x^2 + y^2 - 1)$.

Can somebody help me? We didn't really do Grobner bases that much, we just defined them in general, so a different approach would be appreciated. Also, I have literally no clue where to start, I couldn't follow the course and in the notes there's no mention of an example whatsoever.

Thanks in advance to whoever helps me.

Comment: Which part do you find in particular hard to answer? If you have really no clue on how to compute a primary decomposition of an ideal, you can try like in sage or magma or maple to calculate it and learn from it. Note that you have some nice results on determining whether ideals are radical or primary, like the quotient is reduced iff the ideal is radical or the in quotient all zero-divisors are nilpotent iff the ideal is primary.

Comment: Furthermore, to find the associated primes you can first decompose the ideal into some primary ideals  (irredundant + minimal primary decomposition would be nicer). Then calculate the radicals of the ideals and those will be the associated primes, which will leave you to check which are minimal w.r.t. inclusion. Then switch back into your decomposition to check which of them correspond to the minimal primary ideals.

Comment: For the first ideal, I think it's not radical because $xy$ is in the radical, but not in the ideal. I am pretty sure the decomposition is not unique, and one I found is $(x) \cap (y) \cap (x^2, y^2)$. I am having trouble finding another one though. The associated primes here are $(x), (y)$ and $(x,y)$. Could something like $(x-y) \cap (y) \cap (x^2, y^2)$ work? I'll try and use the programs you listed for $H$.

Comment: You should think of primary decompositions as factoring integers into its primes all the while remembering multiplicity.

Comment: Okay so I should use the same primes, but with different multiplicities? But I don't see how, since I can't put $(x^2)$ or $(y^2)$ in the decomposition...

Comment: This is a redundant decomposition. You shouldn't use different multiplicities as those determine in general different ideals.

Comment: Sorry I edited the comment since I realized it was wrong

Comment: How about something with $(xy)$ and then ...?

Comment: Ah, like $(xy) \cap (x^2) \cap (y^2)$?

Comment: I suggest you to replace $(x^2,y^2)$ by the third power of the maximal ideal $(x,y)$.

Comment: For the second ideal in the first question notice that the corresponding factor ring is reduced, so the ideal is radical, and therefore it equals the intersection of its minimal primes.

Comment: The second question is similar to the first.

Comment: I'm going to add a bounty to the question. Could you please help me? I now need to find decompositions (and tell whether they are radical or not) of only $H$ and $J$.